# .hidden = YES working but .hidden = NO not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView with a custom class in a table cell that also uses a custom class. The UIImageView is connected as a property of the cell's custom class.

The UIImageView has a UITapGestureRecognizer that calls method tapped: I'm passing the cell as the UIImageView's delegate and trying to unhide another view of cell using `cell.theOtherView.hidden = NO` Strangely, to hide `.hidden = YES` works, but to unhide isn't working.

Comment: have you ensured it isn't an issue with redrawing? i.e, `setNeedsDisplay`?

Comment: What would call setNeedsDisplay and where?

Comment: In contrast to hiding, unhiding includes redraw. That at least needs a run loop cycle. How and when do you check, whether the view is still hidden?

Comment: You would be better to have your affected cells redraw based on your data model. When you tap the button, change the data model and reload the affected rows. It could be the cell on screen is nolonger the one you think you are updating?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what's going on without seeing the code you're working with (for example, your code might never actually be reaching the line that sets the view to be hidden), but as MattyAyOh suggested, it's worth trying

`[cell.theOtherView setNeedsDisplay];`

after you set `cell.theOtherView.hidden = YES;`. This will force the view to redraw itself.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that once it's hidden, it no longer received the Tap gesture. Try using `cell.theOtherView.alpha = 0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

you should register your object to .h file first, then you could use hidden function